# How to display nested HTML content with {this.props.children}?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display standard HTML content that is nested within a React modal component. I thought using `{this.props.children}` within the component would allow the nested HTML to be displayed, but the paragraph doesn't appear within the modal when it's open. I want to keep the content within the HTML file and out of the React Component.

A codepen of the issue is [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyQNKN?editors=1010).

HTML:

```js
<div id="testModal">
    <p>Content to be displayed within modal</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isModalOpen: false
        };
        // bind functions
        this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    }

    // close modal
    closeModal() {
        this.setState({isModalOpen: false});
    }

    // open modal
    openModal() {
        this.setState({isModalOpen: true});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="link" onClick={this.openModal}>Click Me</div>
                <div id="modal" className="modal__outter" style={{
                        display: this.state.isModalOpen
                            ? 'block'
                            : 'none'
                    }}>
                    <div className="modal__overlay" onClick={this.closeModal}></div>
                    <div onClick={this.state.closeModal}></div>
                    <div className="modal__container">
                        <div className="modal__header">
                          <button onClick={this.closeModal} className="link">X</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal__content">
                            {this.props.children}
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal__footer">
                            <button className="link" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <Modal />,
    document.getElementById('testModal')
);
```

Comment: Try writing `<Modal><p>Content to be displayed within modal</p></Modal>` instead.

Comment: I've had this problem before 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.props.children` refers to component passed in from your React code, not from HTML file.

So pass the modal content in `ReacDOM.render`

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <Modal>
     <p>Content to be displayed within modal</p>
  </Modal>,
    document.getElementById('testModal')
);
```

Here is the forked [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dance2die/pen/pZQEev).

---

Answer to the comment [is there a way to pass the content in from the HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753217/how-to-display-nested-html-content-with-this-props-children/51753292?noredirect=1#comment90466993_51753292)

Yes, you can but you still need to pass the content somehow.

[image]

I've used `document.getElementById` to get the modal content, and passed it to `<Modal>` as a child.
(If you are planning to use `this.props.children` that is. Or else you can just get the content from HTML with `document.get/querySelect...`)

Here is the updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dance2die/pen/ajQBOG).

Comment: Hi Sung, is there a way to pass the content in from the HTML file? I was hoping to keep the content there and out of the React component file.

Comment: You still need to pass it in the `ReactDOM.render` but you can get the content from HTML using `document.getElement/querySelect...` Refer to the updated answer.